# Executing different commands based on string comparision output

Tags: batch-file

I have a string for eg - `"xxxxxxx New State"` (where `xxx` - hostname of a server) on which i need to execute a certain command if the hostname contains nb and certain set of other commands if hostname doesn't contain letters 'nb' (it would only occur once in the hostname string).

Here is what i have now:-

```
set Hostname="xxxxxxx New State"

echo %Hostname%|findstr /I "nb" > null
If "%errorlevel%"=="0" Goto Found
If "%errorlevel%"=="1" Goto NotFound

:Found

 some commands..

 :NotFound

 Some commands..
```

But this is not working. I used the if else statement too, but that didn't work as well!

Let me know for any more clarification required on the requirement.

-Abhi

Comment: To hid ethe output of a command, use `> nul`; `> null` creates a file called `null`... anyway, do you want to check only the `xxxxxxx` part for `nb`? and please describe what you mean by "not working"...

Comment: Simpler: `if "%Hostname:nb=%" neq "%Hostname%" goto Found`. If Hostname contain "nb" then the first expansion remove it, so the result is different from itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
set Hostname="xxxxxxx New State"    
echo %Hostname%|findstr /I "nb" >nul && goto Found || goto NotFound
goto :eof

:Found    
echo found it
{other commands}
goto :AnotherLabel

:NotFound
echo didn't find it
{other commands}
goto :AnotherLabel

:AnotherLabel
{do more stuff...}
```

The double ampersand `&&` will run the following command if the first command was successful.  The double pipe `||` will run the following command if the first command was NOT successful.

[Here's one source](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) that describes these (and other) redirect symbols.

@Aacini suggested an even simpler method:

```
set Hostname="xxxxxxx New State"

rem If `%Hostname%` contains "nb" then the first expansion removes 
rem it, so the result is different from itself.
if "%Hostname:nb=%" neq "%Hostname%" goto Found. 

rem if the above statement is false, it will do these next commands
rem so there is no need for a :NotFound label
echo didn't find it
{other commands}
goto :AnotherLabel

:Found
echo found it
{other commands}

:AnotherLabel
...
```

Comment: Thanks @Wes Larson. The code worked fine. Just one question - What if i need to execute some other commands after goto statements. Something like this:-

    set Hostname="xxxxxxx New State"    
    echo %Hostname%|findstr /I "nb" >nul && goto Found || goto NotFound
    goto :eof

    :Found    
    echo found it
    goto :eof

    :NotFound
    echo didn't find it
    goto :eof


some commands...

The above code exits after executing one section of code.

-Abhi

Comment: `goto :eof` tells the program to go to End Of File and end the program so that it doesn't continue to process commands.  Here, the `echo` statements are just stand-ins for the actual commands you want to execute.

Comment: I get that.. eof statement is ending the program.. What do i need to do to process further commands after if and goto statements..

Comment: @AbhinandanAithal  See my edited answer.  Instead of `goto :eof`, you can have it `goto :AnotherLabel` where it then executes more commands following `:AnotherLabel`.  But you seem to already understand how to use `goto` and labels, so I'm not quite sure what else you're asking.  It may be better to ask another specific question about this, instead of continuing this comment thread.